Expo Modules - How to emit a Float32Array from native code?
I created a local Expo module and I want to emit a Float32Array from my Swift code to my JavaScript code but I don't know how to do it.
Here is a piece of code that give you more context. Let's say we have a hypothetical Swift class MicrophoneDevice that can get the microphone's live input as buffers of float32s through a listener. Now I want to transfer the buffers to JavaScript as Float32Array. I searched expo doc and they said nothing about it, and I don't know how to do.
import ExpoModulesCore

public class AudioFrameModule: Module {
    let microphone: MicrohphoneDevice

    public func definition() -> ModuleDefinition {
        Name("AudioFrame")

        Events("onFrame")

        Function("start") {
            microphone.listenAudioRawData { (bufferOfFloat32: UnsafeBufferPointer) in
                 self.sendEvent(
                     "onFrame",
                     // I want to pass this UnsafeBufferPointer to
                     // JavaScript side as Float32Array.
                 )
            }
        }
    }
}


